Does free biproduct completion define a lax monoidal functor?
Does free biproduct completion (as described in Definition 2.3 of Coecke-Selby-Tull) define a lax monoidal functor from the category of semi-additive categories to itself ?
I should clarify that here a semi-additive category is a category enriched in CMon. This is described by Definition 1.3 of the above paper.
The monoidal structure of CMon-Cat I want to use is the one inherited from the tensor product of CMon as described in Kelly around equation (1.17).

What monoidal structures are you considering on the category of semi-additive categories, and the category of categories?

I extended my question to include that info

Are you sure you want the cartesian monoidal structure on Cat? Why switch from the tensor product of semiadditive categories? It's surprising to view this construction as landing in plain Cat at all, really.

You are right, I adapted the question accordingly
